# Prevent iOS Users from updating iOS Version Using Apple Configurator

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management, apple-configurator

I have a scenario, where my employees are give iPads and iPhones to help with their daily tasks. There are numerous custom business applications installed on this device.

The problem occurs when these users apply updates to the iOS devices, which leaves created compatibility issues for my custom business applications.

My question is,

Is it possible via the iPhone Configuration Utility or the Apple Configurator, to put these devices in "Supervised Mode", which prevents users from installing these updates, be it OTA or via iTunes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not through official means. Some options are:

1. Install an AppleTV / tvOS beta software profile to the device. This will cause the device to check the wrong repository for updates.
2. Block the update servers from the network that the device uses for internet.
3. Configure a DNS server that allows blocking the resolution of the update servers.

Source and additional information: https://simplemdm.com/2016/09/18/how-to-block-ios-updates/